# Change s3 policy: Is this error caused by a mal-formed policy error or by lack of my permission?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to create a s3 bucket to host some files as a website.

To do so I reckon I need to make each object public. So I created this policy:

```
    {
  "Id": "Policy1554620498897",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1554620491195",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-dummy-bucket",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

it resulted in this error:

[image]

So I changed the resource to `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-dummy-bucket/*",`

now I am getting this:

[image]

What does this 'access denied' is referring to? My lack of permission to change the bucket policy or the resources?

The bucket is newly created and there is no object in it yet.

Comment: @Tim `"Principal": "*"` means all users, whether authenticated or not -- i.e. public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the Access Denied error could be caused by lack of permissions, the most likely explanation is that either your bucket or your entire account is set to disallow public access on buckets.

See [Using Amazon S3 Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html) in the S3 developer guide.

It isn't easy to "accidentally" make a bucket public but people still manage to do it... so AWS has [recently added these settings](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/introducing-amazon-s3-block-public-access/) to make sure you to a certain degree of trouble to expose your content to the world.  The default setting for all new accounts is to disallow public buckets.

The earlier error occurred because `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"` refers to the bucket itself, not the objects in it, and `s3:GetObject` is only applicable to objects, not buckets.  Adding `/*` changes the ARN to refer to all objects in the bucket, not the bucket itself.